# Incompatible type error int[] to int

Tags: java, arraylist, int, java.util.scanner

I am getting an error, incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int. Can someone explain why this is happening and what I need to do to fix it?
Thanks for the help. Here is my code:

```
public static String readFinalQuestionBank() throws Exception
    {   
        File textFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Joseph\\Documents\\School Files - NHCC\\CSci 2002\\FinalQuestionBank_JosephKraemer.txt");  //file location
        ArrayList<String> question;
        ArrayList<String> answer; 
        ArrayList<String> category;
        ArrayList<String> topic;


        int[] i = new int[0];
        String[] structure = {"OO Programming", "Generics", "Bags", "Complexity & Efficiency", "Stacks", "Recursion", "Sorts", "Queues",
                              "Lists", "Iterators", "Searching", "Associative Arrays/Hashing", "Trees/Heaps", "Graphs"};

        try
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(textFile);                   //Scanner to import file

            while(scan.hasNextLine())                               //Iterator - while file has next line
            {
                String qBank = scan.nextLine();                     //Iterator next line
                String[] line = qBank.split("::");             //split data via double colon

                question[i]++ = line[0];    //error is here!!

                System.out.println(qBank);

            }
            scan.close();                  //close scanner

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return "";
    }//end method readFinalQuestionBank
```

Answer (score 1):

`int[]` is an `integer array` type.

`int` is an `integer` type.

You can't convert an array to a number.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared variable `i` as an `int` array and using it to track index of `question[]`. Indices in arrays are represented by 0,1,2,3... which are of type regular `int` and not `int[]`. So you're getting the error `int[] cannot be converted to int`

**Solution:**

Change `int[] i = new int[0];` to `int i = 0;`

And also you have more problems in your code. You're not incrementing index value of `question[]`. So you're always copying the result from `line[]` array into 1st element of `question[]` which makes all the other elements in your array useless. Instead of using `String array`, use `StringBuilder` to save the value.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in the code. declare int as integer, initialise Questions and You have to convert String to integer before assigning it to question.

```
int i = 0;
int [] question = new int [100];
question[i++] = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
```